# How to get contours area of multiple images and separated in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to calculate the contour area of each different images (from a folder path) and then convert into dataframes. Does anyone can give some advise?

The script shows that I can calculate the area of all contours of all images and then convert into dataframe of all contours but I'm searching to separate them for each image.

First image all contours, second all contours, third all contours, etc.

Can someone could guide me to find the code inside de loop?

Thanks

```
import os
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import glob

#load images from specific path
##########################################################
try: 
    os.makedirs("D:\\NBC_new2020_\\data\\concat\\results")
    #os.makedirs("D:\\NBC_new2020_\\images")

except FileExistsError:
    # directory already exists
    pass   

try: 
    os.makedirs("D:\\NBC_new2020_\\images")
    #os.makedirs("D:\\NBC_new2020_\\images")

except FileExistsError:
    # directory already exists
    pass 
############################################################################

#calculate contour of all images from the path
#############################################################
img = []
contours = []
area = []

    for fn in glob.glob("D:\\NBC_new2020_\\images\\*.png"):
        img = cv2.imread(fn, 0)
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 39, 255, 0)
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        for i in contours:
           area.append(cv2.contourArea(i))   



#print(contours)
dframe = pd.DataFrame(area)
print(dframe)
```